# Infill empty (NA) records in dataframe with zeroes

Tags: r

I gave data in format

```
data <-
structure(list(Well_N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("KRT3", "KRT4"), class = "factor"), Date_m = structure(c(16251, 
16281, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16312, 16343, 16373, 16404), class = "Date"), 
QOM = c(132, 36, 39, 211, 45, 108, 161, 30, 31
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("Well_N", 
"Date_m", "QOM"))
```

The `data` output looks like that:

```
  Well_N     Date_m QOM
1   KRT3 2014-06-30 132
2   KRT3 2014-07-30  36
3   KRT3 2014-08-30  39
4   KRT3 2014-09-30 211
5   KRT3 2014-10-30  45
6   KRT4 2014-08-30 108
7   KRT4 2014-09-30 161
8   KRT4 2014-10-30  30
9   KRT4 2014-11-30  31
```

Which function I should use if I would like to infill non-existing values for KRT4 with zeros (0) that each Well have identical date ranges?
The desired output should look like this:

```
  Well_N     Date_m QOM
1   KRT3 2014-06-30 132
2   KRT3 2014-07-30  36
3   KRT3 2014-08-30  39
4   KRT3 2014-09-30 211
5   KRT3 2014-10-30  45
6   KRT3 2014-11-30   0
7   KRT4 2014-06-30   0
8   KRT4 2014-07-30   0
9   KRT4 2014-08-30 108
10  KRT4 2014-09-30 161
11  KRT4 2014-10-30  30
12  KRT4 2014-11-30  31
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be using `data.table`.  My understanding is that if "Date_m" is missing in either one or all of the groups ("well_N"), then the expected output should have the missing "Date_m" in all the groups with "QOM" as 0.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT`), set the key columns (`setkey`) as "Date_m", and "Well_N".  Crossjoin with sequence from `min` to `max` and unique values of "Well_N". Assign "0" to those values that are "NA" for "QOM" and order by "Well_N".

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data), Date_m, Well_N)[
     CJ(Date_m=seq(min(Date_m), max(Date_m), by='1 month'), 
     Well_N=unique(Well_N))][is.na(QOM), QOM:=0][order(Well_N)]
 #    Well_N     Date_m QOM
 # 1:   KRT3 2014-06-30 132
 # 2:   KRT3 2014-07-30  36
 # 3:   KRT3 2014-08-30  39
 # 4:   KRT3 2014-09-30 211
 # 5:   KRT3 2014-10-30  45
 # 6:   KRT3 2014-11-30   0
 # 7:   KRT4 2014-06-30   0
 # 8:   KRT4 2014-07-30   0
 # 9:   KRT4 2014-08-30 108
 #10:   KRT4 2014-09-30 161
 #11:   KRT4 2014-10-30  30
 #12:   KRT4 2014-11-30  31
```

If there are common missing dates ("Date_m") for all the groups of "Well_N" and if the output should not include those dates in the range, we could either reshape to "wide", and then convert to "long"

```
  melt(dcast.data.table(setDT(data), Well_N~Date_m, value.var='QOM',
            drop=FALSE, fill=0), id='Well_N')[order(Well_N)]
```

Or use a modification of the first solution where we replace the `seq(` with `unique(Date_m)`

```
  setkey(setDT(data), Date_m, Well_N)[CJ(Date_m=unique(Date_m), 
       Well_N=unique(Well_N))][is.na(QOM), QOM:=0][order(Well_N)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy in base R with `xtabs`:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(QOM ~ Well_N + Date_m, data))
#   Well_N     Date_m Freq
#1    KRT3 2014-06-30  132
#2    KRT4 2014-06-30    0
#3    KRT3 2014-07-30   36
#4    KRT4 2014-07-30    0
#5    KRT3 2014-08-30   39
#6    KRT4 2014-08-30  108
#7    KRT3 2014-09-30  211
#8    KRT4 2014-09-30  161
#9    KRT3 2014-10-30   45
#10   KRT4 2014-10-30   30
#11   KRT3 2014-11-30    0
#12   KRT4 2014-11-30   31
```

You just need to reorder your data afterwards, using `?order`.

---

Or you can even do it without `order` like this:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(QOM ~ Date_m + Well_N, data))[c(2,1,3)]
#   Well_N     Date_m Freq
#1    KRT3 2014-06-30  132
#2    KRT3 2014-07-30   36
#3    KRT3 2014-08-30   39
#4    KRT3 2014-09-30  211
#5    KRT3 2014-10-30   45
#6    KRT3 2014-11-30    0
#7    KRT4 2014-06-30    0
#8    KRT4 2014-07-30    0
#9    KRT4 2014-08-30  108
#10   KRT4 2014-09-30  161
#11   KRT4 2014-10-30   30
#12   KRT4 2014-11-30   31
```

---

Since it seems they were asking for something different, here's how it could be done in base R (I use "testdata" instead of "data" here):

```
testdata <- merge(expand.grid(Date_m = seq(min(testdata$Date_m), max(testdata$Date_m), 
                by = "1 month"), Well_N = unique(testdata$Well_N)), 
                testdata, by = c("Date_m", "Well_N"), all.x = TRUE)
testdata$QOM[is.na(testdata$QOM)] <- 0
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, here you already dealing with ordering but not the infilling non-existent values?

Comment: @dainys, in both cases I also filled in the non-existent values. See for example that both times the output is 12 rows, as in your expected output.

Comment: @dainys, perhaps you need to clarify what you mean by "non-existent" values. Do you mean the case that akrun described? (For example, non of the KRT* has a Date_m with 2014-07-30 and you want to impute it into the series?) If that's what you mean: I didn't do that in my answer. And strictly speaking, you are not asking for that in your question. So perhaps better to clarify what you mean exactly.

Comment: @dainys, I added a different approach with base R.

Comment: docendo discimus, now your code do exactly what i want. Thanks.